# Mongodb is throwing "connection timed out" error

Tags: pymongo

We are using driver PyMongo to connect python with mongodb it is working fine but, throws "Connection Timedout Exception" for long running scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb `connectTimeoutMS` defaults to 30 seconds.

It defaults to 20 seconds in pymongo.

You may want to increase the timeout, or have a look at optimizing the heavy scripts.

[MongoDB PyMongo Doc](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient)

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have tried increasing the connectiTimeoutMS to 5 minutes. but, it throws the same error after 5 minutes instead 20 seconds. Is there any way i can check if connection is active/live?